# Python Delay on Loop

Tags: python, loops, time, process, delay

I need an alternative to "delay" actions on a LOOP. When using `time.sleep(1)` the whole process pauses for a second. The `print 'something'` should be executed after every 1 second, 50 times and not interrupting the rest of the process.

Actual code:

```
for num in range(50, -1, -1):
    print 'something'
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want, you need to use threads. One thread will do exactly what you did: just count and sleep. The other thread will be "the rest of process", doing whatever it wants, without being interrupted by sleeping.

```
import time
import threading

def count():
    for num in range(50, -1, -1):
        print 'something'
        time.sleep(1)

count_thread = threading.Thread(target=count)
count_thread.start()

for num in range(10, -1, -1):
    print 'main'
    time.sleep(5)

count_thread.join()
```

Comment: Any idea with code? I tried threads.Timer, but it keep repeating the action.

Comment: Did not solve the problem, if a use a function from a class, the hole class pauses(their process and all). E.g: `def count():
    for num in range(50, -1, -1):
        Class().someFunction(num)
        time.sleep(1)`